# Why my object return null from WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf

I have `WCF service` running on my machine.

`[DataContract]` added before class
`[DataMember]` added before each class member.

I didn't add `[DataMember]` before class properties.

```
[OperationContract] added before service interface:

    [OperationContract]
    MyObject GetMyObject();
```

and the service implementation:

```
public MyObject GetXmlFile()
{
    // Bla bla
    MyObject obj = new MyObject ();
    MyObject obj = obj.GetAll();
    return obj;
}
```

When check this with the debugger i can see that the object created successfully in `MyObject obj.GetAll();`
But after that in main program it returned null.

This is how i am return my class object:

```
public MyObject GetAll()
{
    _xmlPath = xmlPath;
    _xml = new XmlDocument();
    _xml.Load(xmlPath);
    GetFirstAttributes(); // Fill up my object with details from XML file
    GetSecondAttributes(); // Fill up my object with details from XML file
    return this;
}
```

Main:

```
        Uri uri = new Uri("http://" + ip + ":8733/MyService");
        ServiceReference1.XMLServiceClient service = new ServiceReference1.XMLServiceClient();
        service.Endpoint.Address = new EndpointAddress(uri);
        ServiceReference1.MyObject xml = service.GetXmlFile();
```

Comment: What are you loading the datamembers from? Are the objects in your data members created in your code or loaded in from json/xml/server?

Comment: That line: `MyObject obj.GetAll();` makes no sense. It doesn't compile. Please show your real code.

Comment: Did you made any changes in de WCF service after you created a ServiceReference in your main project? If so, you need to update your ServiceReference in your main project.

Comment: This is the real code, what i am doing if load XML file and the method GetAll() return my object base on this XML file @ Pazcal de Jonge: what do you mean after ?

Comment: How are you returning a type `MyObject` when the function is defined as returning a type `ParametersXMLFile`? I'm confused.

Comment: It's was mistake, see my update

Comment: Maybe i need to define my class as static ?

Comment: I added how i am return my object, see my update

Comment: Can you post the code for MyObject and your Main code?

Comment: You mean that xml._xml is null in the client? or is the entire xml null?

Comment: The entire in null inside my main code but i have seen that inside GetXmlFile() it wasn't null before return

Answer (score 0):

You must  set OperationContract attribute on your method GetXmlFile